# windows universal listview .contains method seem to not work on panels

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this code i'm testing that's supposed to check a listview control for existing item and return a text "existing item" when it finds one, now I know it's possible to do this using loops but I want to learn to proper use the contains method and couldn't find any real explanation on how to use contains method on panels. the code does seem to work once I remove the stackpanel from the listview but once I add a panel of any type it doesn't seem to work anymore, and i'm really puzzled by why this is happening i'm sure i'm doing something wrong, would appreciate any help here's the code:

```
    private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock testblock = new TextBlock();
        testblock.Text = textBox6.Text;

        StackPanel TestPanel = new StackPanel();
        TestPanel.Children.Add(testblock);

        if (listView.Items.Contains(TestPanel))
        {
            textBox5.Text = "existing item";
        }
     else
        {
            listView.Items.Add(TestPanel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fire the Test_Click event by first time, it will create a new instance of the `StackPanel`. And then it will be added into the `ListView.Items`.

When you fire the Test_Click event again, it will create another new instance of the `StackPanel`. Which is not equal to the first instance of `StackPanel`. So the `listView.Items.Contains(TestPanel)` always return false.

We can define a field in MainPage class that named "TestPanel" and initialize it in the constructor like:

```
private  StackPanel TestPanel;
private  TextBlock testblock;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    testblock = new TextBlock();
    TestPanel = new StackPanel();
    TestPanel.Children.Add(testblock);
}

private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView.Items.Contains(TestPanel))
    {
        textBox5.Text = "existing item";
    }
    else
    {
        testblock.Text = textBox6.Text;
        listView.Items.Add(TestPanel);
    }
}
```